# React - show two elelments on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xp8azn?file=styled.ts,App.tsx)

I know I'm not meant to ask this but is there a better way of doing this.

I have two divs that are positioned on tpo of each other and two buttons to show each of the divs

I'm using `useState` and updating it on button click `<button onClick={() => setBlock('One')}>Btn One</button>`

and then show the div based on the useState value.

```
{block === 'One' && <div className="FlexContainerColOne"></div>}
```

I'm asking cos I've never seen like this before `block === 'One'` `and not sure if this the best way to do this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { FlexContainer } from './styled';

const App = () => {
  const [block, setBlock] = React.useState('One');
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setBlock('One')}>Btn One</button>
      <button onClick={() => setBlock('Two')}>Btn Two</button>

      <FlexContainer>
        {block === 'One' && <div className="FlexContainerColOne"></div>}
        {block === 'Two' && <div className="FlexContainerColTwo"></div>}
      </FlexContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Post your relevant code here and don't make people who are interested in helping you click through to a third party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch between two divs, just create a state to toggle it

```
const App = () => {
  const [toggleBlock, setToggleBlock] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setToggleBlock(!toggleBlock)}>Toggle</button>

      <FlexContainer>
        {toggleBlock ? (
          <div className="FlexContainerColOne"></div>
        ) : (
          <div className="FlexContainerColTwo"></div>
        )}
      </FlexContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```